# how I can show text item in shadow box in Android?

Tags: android

when I drag item I wanna show text in shadow section in another words I wanna item text in shadow section ( when user long click and wanna drop to another place ) !
here in startdrag I have data and item text when I call myshadow I can't set text in shadow box (clor is yellow ) .

```
OnItemLongClickListener listSourceItemLongClickListener = new OnItemLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position,
        long id) {

    // Selected item is passed as item in dragData
    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item(lv_arr[position]);

    String[] clipDescription = { ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN };
    ClipData dragData = new ClipData((CharSequence) v.getTag(),
            clipDescription, item);
    DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new MyDragShadowBuilder(v);

    v.startDrag(dragData, // ClipData
            myShadow, // View.DragShadowBuilder
            lv_arr[position], // Object myLocalState
            0); // flags

    // commentMsg = v.getTag() + " : onLongClick.\n";
    // comments.setText(commentMsg);

    return true;
}
}
private static class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder{
  private static Drawable shadow;

public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v) {
    super(v);
    shadow = new ColorDrawable(Color.LTGRAY);
}

@Override
public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point size, Point touch) {
    int width = getView().getWidth();
    int height = getView().getHeight();

    shadow.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
    size.set(width, height);
    touch.set(width / 2, height / 2);
}


@Override
public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
    shadow.draw(canvas);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can override the `onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas)` (that you are actually already overriding) and use the canvas object reference to call the method `drawText` passing the text that you want to be there.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

yeah , thank you Yup ; 
I just added , that's work for me !

```
    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {

        shadow.draw(canvas);
        super.onDrawShadow(canvas);

    }
```